# How to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and get results of the query?

Tags: postgresql

I have written a custom [PostgreSQL client](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) and I want to add a function that would automatically capture query execution time.

The current `executionTime` value in Slonik results records the total query execution time, including the roundtrip and parsing. In order to capture the actual query execution time, I plan to prefix every query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, parse the explanation and capture the results of the query. However, I cannot find a way to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and capture the actual query result (in addition to explain output).

How to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and get results of the query?

Comment: You can't - you can **either** run `analyze` **or** get the results.

Comment: There are workarounds, e.g. one could use `auto_explain` and capture the notice during the execution. I am looking for a solution that ideally does not require to configure the database instance outside of the query/ procedure.

Comment: `auto_explain` also runs the query separately from the `explain` step

Comment: But there is nothing stopping you from getting the explain output. The question asks how to run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and get results of the query, which `auto_explain` solves.

Comment: Well, you can do the same in your program: run the query, then once it's finished run `explain (analyze)` afterwards - that's precisely what auto_explain does

Comment: Running `explain analyze` after the query will re-run the same query, i.e. it will run query twice.

Comment: Correct - and that's exactly what `auto_explain` does. There is no other option (which I already stated)

Comment: Are you saying that if I executed `UPDATE foo SET bar = now()` and if `auto_explain` was enabled, then the query would run twice?

Comment: By default auto_explain only runs a simple explain, not an `explain (analyze)`. But if you enable `auto_explain.log_analyze` it apparently runs `explain (analyze)` - I have no idea if it does that for DML statements as well

Comment: No, auto_explain.log_analyze doesn't run the query twice.

Comment: It didn't make much sense that `auto_explain.log_analyze` would run a query twice, but I couldn't find a source that would explicitly states it doesn't either. @jjanes is there any official reference you could share?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a negative to be documented as such.  The note at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html about the performance impact of log_analyze certainly implies that every execution is instrumented from the beginning, not gone back to to re-execute only if it passes log_min_duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
set auto_explain.log_min_duration TO 0;
set auto_explain.log_level TO notice ;
set auto_explain.log_analyze to on;
```

then the client will receive the execution analysis.  You just need to make it capture that message and distinguish them from other messages that might come along on the same channel.  If you need an example, 'psql' does capture and display these messages (but doesn't interpret them).

Comment: What are the defaults for these, if, for example, we realized that our client now just shows query plans whenever we try to run a query? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris The default for  auto_explain.log_level is LOG, which means the plan just gets written to the server's logfile, and not sent to the client.  But if this somehow did get changed to NOTICE, then the client should still be getting the query results in addition to the plan, so that is probably not what I causing your problem.  I don't know what could cause what you are seeing.